# Transfer multiple images through TCP socket/s

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, file-transfer

I try to create an application in Java, that I have a grid of images. Each image must be loaded from a remote server through TCP connection(s).

My question is which is the best way to do this? Use one TCP socket and request all the images through this, or open a new socket for each image request?

----- UPDATE -----

Thank you all for your replies.

I update the post to write some extra information which answers in some of your questions.

- The system client/server is in a local (home) network and it will not
  tranfer data throw Internet, so the connection bandwidth it's not a
  problem.
- Also the grid will contains the thumbnails of the images, the image I
  will loaded on demand when the use double clicks an thumbnail on a seperate socket.
- I write the code from the client and the server both are writen in java.
- we have one client may to connect to small number of server's but only one per time no paraller connections to different servers.

What I think, if use a single socket I must seperate the images size, image name so I must for each image send a string with name, and a long for the size. Throw the single socket it's better to request the images all together at the begin of connection and later send all the images in a serial way one to one, or throw the single socket send a image request get the image reply, after request the second image and get the second reply.

If I use multiple sockets, one socket for each image request I want to have a maximum number of open sockets, may I use an threadpool and use one runnable to manage one image transfer throw one socket?

Thank you again.

Comment: I update my question to add some extra information

Answer (score 0):

If you're in charge for both the server and the client, there is no reason not to use a single connection to load several (all) images at once. It will of course be more efficient.

Comment: In web servers multiple connections can be beneficial if some images are in the disk cache and others are not.  It all depends if the channel is simple like a single chunked HTTP connection or more complex like a multi-stream SPDY or even SCTP.  More likely such micro-optimisations are not required.

Comment: I'd seriously dispute "more efficient".  Sure, it avoids multiple TCP handshakes, but on a large transfer those are a negligible portion of the transfer time.  It also _prevents_ parallel downloads which definitely _is_ more efficient.

Comment: How is it more efficient if you lose more of your bandwidth in TCP handshakes? It's not like having two parallel transfers would magically double your bandwidth. Moreover, TCP uses slow-start (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slow-start), which reduces the multi-connection option speed even more.

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple sockets would allow for the possibility of performing multiple transfers in parallel, if bandwidth and server capacity allows.

Another downside of using a single socket for all transfers is that you must find some way for the client to detect the end of each file.  Using a socket per file simplifies that because the remote server can simply close the connection after each file.

I can't think of any particular advantage of going for a single socket other than a probably negligible decrease in set up time for the TCP sockets.

So on balance I would go for a socket per file.

I'd also note that HTTP uses a combination of both - parallel connections *and* multiple downloads per socket.  However the latter optimisation is mostly beneficial when transferring lots of small files, it's unlikely to be useful when transferring 100k+ image files.

Comment: Same problems as with HTTP, uses more resources on the server and the connection times may not be insignificant for so many short lived connections.  Generally for internal applications the easier development time might be preferential if not using 3rd party middleware.

Comment: I _did_ say "if server capacity allows".

Answer (score 0):

I think use one TCP socket is better because you have a grid of images and if you want to open a socket for each image the number of socket will be increase and maybe cause problems.
You can keep the socket open to all images transfer and then close it.It has easier management.

Comment: Also, if you want to go really tricky you can even implement kind of a multiplexing image transfer. Transfer a block of data from each image serially. Then in the receiving end store the blocks into corresponding image.

There are two issues with this approach. First is of course that you need to be able to have control of the sending code. Second is that you need to create a "protocol" that first send metadata of each image, e.g. filename, format and length. This creates additional complexity you might not want.

However, by using this you can effectively transfer N pictures in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just like to point out that those answers that are emphatically asserting that one connection is more efficient or faster than multiple connections ... or *vice versa* ... are missing a couple of important issues:

- The optimal solution depends on a number of factors such as:

  - how large / small the images are (in terms of bytes to be transmitted),
  - network bandwidth and latency for the route between the client and server (which may change)
  - network congestion
  - server load / overload
- You also need to decide whether you are optimizing for a single client, or for multiple clients using the same application; i.e. whether you "give a damn" about the impact of your application on other users of the service.

---

My gut feeling is that you will probably get better throughput with a few connections instead of one.  But there will be a point where opening more connections will actually *reduce* throughput due to a combination of network congestion and various client/server side load issues.  Making this work as fast as possible under all conditions is really, really hard.